# Checkbox value always 0 after insert into database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, checkbox

I am building a website using `Asp.Net MVC`. I have successfully inserted my form data into the database. However, I got a problem with my checkbox, the value is always 0 in my database even if the checkbox is checked.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="username" class="col-form-label">Name:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" **id="username" name="username" **>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <input type="checkbox" **id="user_privilage" name="user_privilage" **>
                    <label for="user" class="col-form-label">User</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> 
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
    </div>
}
```

here is the code in controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UserMaintenance(User collection)
{
    try
    {
        List<object> lst = new List<object>();
        lst.Add(collection.username);
        lst.Add(collection.user_privilage);
        object[] allitems = lst.ToArray();
        int output = db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("insert into DATABASE(username,user_privilage) values (@p0,@p1)", allitems);
        if(output>0)
        {
            ViewBag.msg = "User has been added";
        }
        return View();
        //return RedirectToAction("UserMaintenance");
    }
    catch {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Does anyone know what happened?

Comment: Always use view models

Comment: You not giving the checkbox a value (so it posts back `"on"` if its checked). Use a view model with a `bool` property and strongly bind to your model with `@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.yourProperty)` and ditto for all your controls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using pure html markup checkbox in that you need to set value to checkbox as true.

> Model

[image: Model]

> View

[image]

> Views at Runtime

[image]

> POST Action Method

We have checked checkbox and submitted form we must get value true in user_privilage model property.

In Same way if we do for unchecking checkbox then we will get false value.

[image]